# Comparing line by line of a CSV file Java

Tags: java, file, csv

A sample of my code is as follows:

```
File myFile = new File("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\fileName.csv");

try {
    Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myFile);
    while(myScanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String data = myScanner.nextLine();
        String[] fields = data.split(",");
        name = fields[0];
        age = Integer.parseInt(fields[1]);
        birthday = fields[2]; 
        storeVisitDate = fields[3];
        }
        Person myPerson = new Person(name,age,birthday,storeVisitDate);
    } 
}
```

I have a separate class called "Person", which instantiates an object based on the input of the CSV file.

What I am tasked to do is to prepare an output that generates the name, age, birthday and store visit date of a person on one line, however, if this person has multiple store visit dates, I should only display the store visit date in the following line.

How am I able to compare the current line to the next line to see if it is the same name of the person?
Also, I am not allowed to create any ArrayLists/Lists.

Sample of .CSV file contents:
[Sample of .CSV file contents](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4uH0M.png)

Thank you.

Person Class:

```
public class Person{
private String name;
private int age;
private String birthday;
private String dateOfVisit;

public Person(String data)
{
String[] info = data.split(",");
name = info[0];
age = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
birthday = info[2];
dateOfVisit = info[3];
}
}
```

Comment: That for loop really doesn't make sense -- where do you use `i` within the loop? What is the purpose of the loop? Just because you're extracting data from an array doesn't automatically mean that you should use a for-loop, especially a "futile" loop as you've written.

Comment: `Person myPerson(name,age,birthday,storeVisitDate);` has syntax error.

Comment: If this were my code, Person would have a `List<String>` that holds the storeVisitDate data. I'd also make sure that Person overrides equals and hashCode, perhaps using name and birthday, that allows easy comparison of 2 Person objects for equality.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yup, but probably that variable is kind of `lastVisitDate` - i'm just making assumptions. According to my previous comment, there're more syntax errors here... but we can assume the proper variables were declared...

Comment: sorry, I just realized that I the initiation of the Person object is wrong... it should be Person myPerson = new Person(name,age,birthday,storeVisitDate).

Comment: Also, everything is a String, other than the age.

Also, you are right I didn't need a loop in the above code.... I thought that I would need it to have something to do with reading each of the "fields" to check for comparison or something.

Comment: [edit] your question and add code for your `Person` class. Also post a sample of the contents of the CSV file. Is the file sorted, alphabetically, by _name_?

Comment: It is sorted by name... but not alphabetically.

Comment: That would be "grouped" by name.  If true, then simply compare current name to previous name and if different output person; otherwise continue - and then handle last line case.  Something like `if (name != null && !name.equals(info[0]))` right before assigning to `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a classic data processing exercise and reminds me of when I learned COBOL programming over 30 years ago. The basic algorithm is as follows:

1. Read the next entry from the file. In your case the details of a person.
2. If the person just read is different to the last person read then complete processing for the last person and start processing the new person and set the last person details to the new person details.
3. If the person just read is the same as the last person read then continue handling the current person.

In your case two `Person`s are the same if they have the same `name`.
According to the above algorithm, you need to save the last `Person` details.
Below is the implementing java code.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Person {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private String birthday;
    private String dateOfVisit;

    public Person(String data) {
        String[] info = data.split(",");
        name = info[0];
        age = Integer.parseInt(info[1]);
        birthday = info[2];
        dateOfVisit = info[3];
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public String getBirthday() {
        return birthday;
    }

    public String getDateOfVisit() {
        return dateOfVisit;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return String.format("%s %d %s ", name, age, birthday);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File myFile = new File("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\fileName.csv");
        Person lastPerson = null;
        int count = 0;
        try (Scanner myScanner = new Scanner(myFile)) {
            while (myScanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String data = myScanner.nextLine();
                Person p = new Person(data);
                if (lastPerson == null  ||  !lastPerson.getName().equals(p.getName())) {
                    if (count == 1) {
                        System.out.println(lastPerson.getDateOfVisit());
                    }
                    System.out.print(p);
                    count = 1;
                    lastPerson = p;
                }
                else {
                    if (count == 1) {
                        System.out.println();
                        System.out.println(lastPerson.getDateOfVisit());
                    }
                    count++;
                    System.out.println(p.getDateOfVisit());
                }
            }
            // Print the visit date of the last person in the CSV file.
            if (count == 1) {
                System.out.println(lastPerson.getDateOfVisit());
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you need to close your `Scanner`. The above code achieves this via [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)

Using the sample data you provided, the output of the above code is as follows.

```
Aliza Burn 20 01/01/2000 
07/20/2018
08/15/2016
04/14/2014
Edward Chase 45 02/14/1974 
05/05/2009
06/20/2014
Penny Lane 15 06/20/2004 
03/13/2018
05/06/2018
Josef Hunt 89 09/28/1930 08/21/2019
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the variable count?

Comment: @royalducky28 to handle the very first row of the file and the very last row. Try removing it from the code and then run the modified code and see what happens.